# winforms setup file enhancement

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

Hi i've created a setup file using c# winforms. Now i'm going to do some changes in the code and want to rebuild the same setup file. Every thing going fine. But when i try to install the new setup file it is asking application alreay exist.

I dont want to do like this. If alreay exist it should ask me like update, remove, reinstall like this? So where do i setup all these things?

thank you

Comment: see, if you installed old version and then change the version of the setup and then build and install the new one, it will not give this message, but if you install the same setup twice it will give.

Answer (score 0):

After Producing a new version of the setup you should change the version number which will change the ProductCode after that it will replace the old version automatically.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. Still it is saying like another version of application already exist in the system. But i want the message like overwrite,update,reinstall like this.. how is it possible

Answer (score 0):

I have no personal experience, but rumor has it that the setup included with Visual Studio has bugs and problems similar to the one you're experiencing. I've heard [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is better.